# Query to sort a table in sections and filling in a section from the middle out

Tags: sql, sql-server, sorting

I have a table of slots, say numbered 1 to 15. These slots are logically divided in 3 sections of 5 slots each. I would like to arrange them in sections such that the middle ones fill out first and then move out towards the edges, thus the first and last of each section filling out last.
So if a table looks like this:

Slots in the original table (| represents a boundary between segments)

```
| 1,2,3,4,5 | 6,7,8,9,10 | 11,12,13,14,15|
```

I would like to run a query that would return the result as such where each segment has the middle slot listed first, then the ones next to the middle, then ones at the end of each section.

```
| 3,4,2,5,1 | 8,9,7,10,6 | 13,14,12,15,11 |
```

Is this possible with SQL?

I've tried something like this but it doesn't quite work out:

```
DECLARE @SegSize INT = 5;

DECLARE @NoSeg INT = 3;

SELECT SlotLoc
FROM Slots
ORDER BY ABS((SlotLoc%@SegSize)-CEILING(@SegSize/2 + 1))
```

Comment: How is `| 1,2,3,4,5 | ...` actually stored? Is this just a big comma-separated string in a single column, or is this your visualization of data stored in a different way? Could you show the actual table and an insert statement that populates the slots so we can work out what your query is trying to do?

Comment: Hi Aaron. No, actually these are stored as individual slots values in their own records. The table has a bunch of other entries but I simplified it to just slot numbers.

Comment: Also, does the _value_ of the slot matter or does its _position_? Are these ordered 1-5 because of their values or is it just coincidence / simplified?

Comment: Slot ordering is important because each section is from slot x to slot y.

Comment: Ok, show us _how_. Is there another column that indicates that `3` is in fact the third slot in that segment? Or is it third because it has the third lowest value? Say the values are `2,4,5,6,11` or `2,6,11,5,4` ... I know you have tried to simplify the problem, but in most cases this just makes it harder to solve (or at least harder to solve _right_).

Comment: And since we're exploring, what if there are 12 rows or 14 rows? What if there are two slots with the same value but they are not adjacent? `2,5,6,2,6`

Comment: 3 is just the third slot of the entire cabinet which are numbered from 1 to 15 in order. Therefore slots 1-5 are seg 1, 6-10 seg 2, and 11-15 seg 3. The segments are not defined in DB. They are just a logical separation.

Comment: Each slot value is unique. It represents the actual slot in a cabinet. The number of rows is always fixed as well.

Comment: @AaronBertrand already asked, but let me second his request. Actual DML/DDL sample data is going to be extremely important here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This depends on a lot of assumptions, like fixed number of rows, and also assumes you don't care about the order of slots 2/3 and 4/5. Given this data:

```
CREATE TABLE #slots(slot tinyint);

INSERT #slots(slot) SELECT TOP (15) 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) 
  FROM sys.all_objects;
```

This query gets pretty close to exactly your desired output (except sometimes you listed the higher slot value first, sometimes last):

```
;WITH x AS 
(
  SELECT slot, segment = (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY slot)-1)/5 FROM #slots
),
y AS 
(
  SELECT slot,segment,
    rn = ABS(3 - ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY segment ORDER BY slot)) 
  FROM x
)
SELECT slot FROM y ORDER BY segment, rn;
```

Results:

```
Slot
----
3
4
2
1
5
8
9
7
10
6
13
14
12
15
11
```

Cleanup:

```
DROP TABLE #slots;
```